# the role of index in performance in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

why defining index for mysql tables increase performance in queries haveing join?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are interested in a specific topic in a book, you go to the back of the book and find it alphabetically in the index. The index tells you the page number(s) where the topic is discussed. Then you jump straight to the pages that you are interested in. Much, much faster than reading the whole book.

It's the same in a database. The index means that you can jump to the joining rows instead of scanning every row in the table looking for a match.

Have a look at how a clustered index works (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443.aspx). You can have one of those per table.

This artical explains how a non clustered index works (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484.aspx). You can have as many of them as you want.

Both of these articles are about Microsoft Sql Server, but the theory behind indexes is the same across all relational database management systems.

Indexes do have an associated cost. Every time an insert/update is performed on the table, the effected index(es) may have to be updated also. And of course indexes take up space - but that is not really an issue for most of us. So you need to balance the performance benefits of faster joins or filtering against the costs of inserts and updates.

As a guide, you will generally want an index that matches each of the columns included in a join or where clause:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Customer 
WHERE 
    RegistrationDate > @registrationDate 
    AND RegistrationCountry = @registrationCountry;
```

So an index on the Customer table that includes the RegistrationDate and RegistrationCountry columns would speed up this query. Since we are using a ">" in our query, this would be a good candidate for a clustered index (the first article shows that a clustered index physically arranges the data in index order so range queries can very quickly isolate a range of the index).

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Customer c
    INNER JOIN Order o
        ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
        AND o.OrderType = @orderType
```

Here, we would want an index on the Customer table that contains the CustomerID column. And we'd want an index on the Order table that contains the CustomerID and the OrderType columns. Then both sides of the join will not need to do a table scan.

Typically there will only be a small number of ways that data is queried from a table, so you won't get index overload. Lots of indexes is sometimes a sign that your tables have mixed concerns and could be normalized.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read up on the basics of database [indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29). Indexes are basically used to organize data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that sometimes it can be significantly faster to replace the JOIN query with two smaller queries, then join them in PHP or whatever language is calling MySQL. So try both and time them to see which is better for the particular situation, but bear in mind that the "fastest" solution may change as database size increases.